# Review section suddenly shows 1.4k low quality posts but there are none to review

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

Seems like something is gone wrong:

[image: review fail]

I don't see any of the 1.4k Low Quality Posts. I guess that I somehow see the total/global numbers instead of my personal counter.

Comment: No repro here. It looks like they re-arranged how some of the queues are listed. For instance I now see "Close Votes" at the top. Perhaps you just happened to catch it during a transition? What happens when you force a reload?

Comment: Although, for what it's worth, the review queue for "Closed Questions" here on [meta] shows a count of 43 questions, but none are displayed when I click the link.

Comment: Okay, check that. I'm seeing something similar, just not the same counts.

Comment: Had the same with close-votes. Easy to solve: Just click some other link, then click the "review" link again, then enter the area (low quality posts in your case, close-votes in mine) -- et voila, there they are. Maybe a temporary hick-up, I guess.

Comment: Urgs... I take that back, no longer works for me either: 242 close votes -- but whatever I do, no items for me...

Comment: I can confirm the same, while the count is different, way below the ones from the question.

Comment: Well, the main account review seems to be working appropriately again. It also seems that the order of the queues is dynamic, with the most populated queue at the top.

Comment: Network-wide issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144627/review-tab-stuck-at-566-low-quality-242-close-votes-0-suggested-edits

Comment: @AlEverett Looks different from the symptoms I experience

Comment: Are you still seeing this? What was described there was pretty much what I was seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers have returned to normal (that is 0, 0, 0 for me).